# QTimer, Parametrized slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtimer

I am writing an app for  relay controller. I have a function that opens/closes relay:

```
void setRelay(unsigned int relay_number, bool state);
```

Now I want to make some button to open an relay for lets say 1sek.

I want  to do th sth like this:

```
void on_button_clicked()
{
    setRelay(1, true);
    QTimer::singleShot(1000,this,SLOT(setRelay(1,false)))
}
```

Yes, I know that the signals dont work that way.
Is there any way to change the signal emitted from timer, so it will close up an relay. Closest thing I came up is this:

```
QTimer::singleShot(1000,this,SLOT(relay_1_off()));
```

and then I have to make a slot per relay to close it:

```
void relay_1_off(){
    setRelay(1,false);
}
```

Could it be done without making so many slots, anyone have some more clever way?
Greetings

Comment: What is the version of Qt What do you have?

Comment: I am using the newest, 5.9 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Qt5 you can use the lambda functions:

[void QTimer::singleShot(int msec, Functor functor)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot-4)

```
QTimer::singleShot(1000, [&](){
    setRelay(1,false);
});
```

Comment: Is  [&] really necessary? I think [] will do in this case.

Comment: You have to pass it the context, if setRelay is a method of `this` then it's enough to pass it to you: `QTimer::singleShot(1000, [this](){`

Comment: @KarolŻurowski If it worked for you, do not forget to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: I sure did. Thank you once more :)

Comment: @KarolŻurowski No, check the following link so you can see how an answer is marked as correct: [tour] :P